# Where in metadata are Organization-Wide Sharing defaults for Calendar stored?

Tags: sharing, metadata, calendar

I changed Sharing Settings for Calendar to "Hide Details and Add Events", but I don't know how to put it in metadata *.xml files, is it even possible?

Comment: Couldn't find this anywhere to be documented but looks like there's no corresponding Metadata type for Calendar's sharing settings. Only reasoning to validate this is that Sharing settings are only available on [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) on the [SharingModel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm#meta_type_SharingModel) field type which does not list the options those are available for Calendar.

Comment: @JayantDas Yeah, I checked Task, Activity, and Event CustomObject, expecting to maybe find something special, but they are all just ControlledByParent. I think it's a documentation issue more than anything.

Comment: @sfdcfox Agreed. It looks like this is not supported and not documented either. I searched every possible location I could but of no use. With this instance I have come across at least 3 of features which do not work as expected or are not clearly documented. I am still awaiting for one of my cases to be responded back around similar documentation issue. Off topic, do you know how to raise such issues to Salesforce to fix issues identified with documentation? Because not every time one can actually open a case.

Comment: @JayantDas What I generally do is leave feedback on the page, then send a tweet to salesforcedocs. They usually respond pretty quickly, and the documentation team loves getting messages.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Just mentioning fyi .. thanks for the recommendation. Had tweeted Salesforce Docs and got their response. Have been using that twitter handle to highlight any documentation issues and they have been acknowledging those as well. Very good way of reaching out to the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on @sfdcfox's recommendation, I tweeted to [@salesforcedocs](https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs) and finally got the response.

Calendar's are **not** supported in Metadata, and thus you won't have any opportunity to add it in any metadata xml file.

As per the response, the one mentioned as "Public and Resource Calendars" on [Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm)
 signifies "Calendar".

[Here's the link](https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs/status/1057731041975197696) to the response from Salesforce Docs team (snapshot below).

[image]

Comment: +1 Or "Calendars and Public Resources". Etc. I never would have guessed this phrase meant "public calendars."

Comment: That’s true :) good that it will be corrected.